# Does ROLLBACK TRAN honor LOCK_TIMEOUT value?

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction

I have a following stored procedure on my system.

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
  SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000
  UPDATE tbl
  COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

UPDATE tbl went into timeout and ROLLBACK TRAN also failed because of timeout.

Question is: is this possible?

Comment: ROLLBACK TRAN rolls back a transaction. That's it! Please clarify what you are asking

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: So, your question is that you have a transaction that did neither commit nor rollback? And how or why did this happen - or if it is possible at all?

Comment: Yeah, the question is - is this possible?

Comment: Just curious: why are you not just doing 
`BEGIN TRAN; SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 10000; UPDATE tbl; COMMIT TRAN` ? Is it important to hide it if the transaction fails?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.

SQL Server will always finish the `ROLLBACK`, no matter what. Even if you cut the power to the system in the middle of the `ROLLBACK`, the `ROLLBACK` will continue after the power is returned. `ROLLBACK` also ignores any connection interruptions and `LOCK_TIMEOUT` settings. In fact, a connection interruption will start a `ROLLBACK` if there is an open transaction at the time of interruption.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have just run this successfully. Also i would not expect rollback to honor the lock_timout.

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
  SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 100
  select * from sys.sysobjects a, sys.sysobjects b with (holdlock)
PRINT @@TRANCOUNT
  COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
PRINT @@TRANCOUNT
```